# Form positioning problem

Tags: css, layout

I have a Windows program which generates forms.

It takes the Top/Left properties at form design time in the Windows program and generates HTML to display the form, using `position: absolute` and the original Top/Left.

Now I want to split my HTML page into three panes/sections :

1) a menu bar across the top
2) the form, as designed in the windows program
3) a submit button, below the form

I presume that there is some very simple way to do this, using divs (if I *must*, I can enclose the form in a , but would rather avoid that).

**The main point is that the coordinates in 2) will now need to be relative to 2)**

I hope that that is clear, please ask me if not.

---

@YTi Jiang asked for some sample generated HTML, so here is the simplest I could think of - a text input box. Feel free to ask for any kind of example, but I really think that I am just asking for some "classic", like a "classic top menu/page body/footer" or whatever the CSS/HML gurus call it..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Input data</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<style type="text/css">
  body { font: 12px Arial; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="HTTP://localhost/b/submitted.php" method="post">

<div class="TEdit" id="TextEditBox1" style="position: absolute; top:56px; left: 72px; width: 121px; height: 21px;">
  <input type="text" name="TextEditBox1">
</div>

<div class"submit_button" style="position:absolute; top:102px; left:132px;"><input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Does it make any difference that it is a form and not just a plain HTML page?

Comment: It would be nice if you could show us some of the HTML that's been generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by the sounds of it, you want a fixed header and footer but the content to move with the page scrolls. in which case have a look at the source of this sample page: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/basics2.html which does exactly that!

Comment: +1 thanks. No, I am fine with fixed header, body & footer.  Or, rather, the header is probably a fixed size, big enough for a horizontal menu, page can be as long as it takes, just contain the body, and then a footer for the submit button